# How do I verify Android in-app-billing transactions on MY server?

Tags: php, android, in-app-billing

I have made an Android app where items can be purchased using [in-app-billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html). When an item is purchased the transaction can easily be synced between Android Market and the phone - to be used in the app. But, I need MY server to be aware of the purchase. The decision to deliver app-specific data should be made on my server, not in the client app.

E.g.

1. User buys item X from Android Market.
2. Transaction data Y is sent to the client.
3. Client sends Y to my server.
4. Client asks the server to deliver content for X.
5. Server delivers content **if Y is valid**. How can this be accomplished?

**Q:** How do I verify that transaction data coming from the Android client (presumably originating from Google servers) is not fake? I.e. a hacker didn't generate the data.

Google Server -> Android client -> My server -> Android client

Perhaps this is more of a PHP question than anything else. Exactly what should my server script (PHP) do in order to verify that the retrieved data is real?

Comment: here's the simple code that works well in my projects:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35718040/2710505

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use openssl_verify ($data, $signature, $key)

The variables $data and $signature should be sent from the android client to your php server using https. The transaction contains both of these items. Send that to your servers before you acknowledge the transaction on the client.(see documentation here - http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html)

The variable $key is your google public key available from your publisher account from the Licensing & In-app Billing panel. Copy the public key and use that in your php code, preferably using a config file you install on your servers rather than in your actual php code.

If the openssl_verify call succeeds you should store the order numbers on your servers and ensure they are unique so they cannot be replayed. Be aware that a single data receipt and signature pair could contain many order numbers though its usually one order.

Comment: This is a very large document. I have questions. What is $data? What is $signature? How do we know we're getting a request from Google's servers? Where do we send the response back?

Comment: openssl_verify is a PHP function call to its openssl library - http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php. In terms of checking google's servers - I don't think google supports mutual authentication (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) otherwise you just check the SSL certs similar to a browser when you connect to google's servers.

Comment: @Agamemnus - Note that you don't need to call google's servers - you only need to call your server using SSL. You do need to fetch the public key from google's servers but you could do that out-of-band

Comment: I'm very confused. If I were to authenticate a purchase using Paypal's systems, for example, Paypal sends a message to my server authenticating the transaction. If it is a Google Play in-app purchase, and my server sends something to the user, how does my server know that there was a purchase, and who made it? WAIT.. are you saying that Google sends a $signature string that decodes to $data, and I can use their public key (where?) to decode and verify? Google's example is starting to make sense but it still seems really abstract.

Comment: @Agamemnus - Google sends the signature and data to the phone/device. The phone sends this payload to your server. You are verifying this payload was actually sent by google - signed by google. You still need to check the payload isn't being replayed and the payload could have more than one order.

Comment: Ok, and the public key id is my app's key ID. I'm going senile. I think I got it all. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

We used [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary).

Install that as a project in Eclipse and let your project import it as a library.

We implemented BillingController.IConfiguration, something like

```
import net.robotmedia.billing.BillingController;

public class PhoneBillingConfiguration implements BillingController.IConfiguration{
    @Override
    public byte[] getObfuscationSalt() {
        return new byte[] {1,-2,3,4,-5,6,-7,theseshouldallberandombyteshere,8,-9,0};
    }

    @Override
    public String getPublicKey() {
        return "superlongstringhereIforgothowwemadethis";
    }
}
```

Then for our application, we extended `Application`:

```
public class LocalizedApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

//      BillingController.setDebug(true);
        BillingController.setConfiguration(new PhoneBillingConfiguration());
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest includes this (and all the other stuff)

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".LocalizedApplication"   <!-- use your specific Application  -->
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >

    <!-- For billing -->
    <service android:name="net.robotmedia.billing.BillingService" />
        <receiver android:name="net.robotmedia.billing.BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

We implemented `ISignatureValidator`

```
public class PhoneSignatureValidator implements ISignatureValidator {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private PhoneServerLink mServerLink;


    private BillingController.IConfiguration configuration;

    public PhoneSignatureValidator(Context context, BillingController.IConfiguration configuration, String our_product_sku) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        mServerLink = new PhoneServerLink(context);
        mServerLink.setSku(our_product_sku);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean validate(String signedData, String signature) {
        final String publicKey;
        if (configuration == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(publicKey = configuration.getPublicKey())) {
            Log.w(BillingController.LOG_TAG, "Please set the public key or turn on debug mode");
            return false;
        }
        if (signedData == null) {
            Log.e(BillingController.LOG_TAG, "Data is null");
            return false;
        }
        // mServerLink will talk to your server
        boolean bool = mServerLink.validateSignature(signedData, signature);
        return bool;
    }

}
```

It's the last few lines above that call your class that will actually talk to your server.

Our PhoneServerLink starts out something like this:

```
public class PhoneServerLink implements GetJSONListener {

    public PhoneServerLink(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public boolean validateSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
        return getPurchaseResultFromServer(signedData, signature, false);
    }

    private boolean getPurchaseResultFromServer(String signedData, String signature,  boolean async) {  
            // send request to server using whatever protocols you like 
    }

}
```

Comment: The code looks nice, but I believe this is more of a server-side issue. Exactly how can my server code determine if a request (transaction info) is valid?

Comment: ah crap; I answered everything *except* your question!  Well, maybe it will be good for someone who has the opposite issue.  ;-)

Comment: fixed.   (really surprising that github didn't account for that when they changed it!)

Comment: @ThunderRabbit I want to write a code for In app purchase in which i want to provide facility to buy video inside my app and videos are stored in my own server..So do you have any Tutorial for this and "Android Billing Library" Secure to use in our project??

Answer (score 4):

Transaction data is signed with a private key specific to your app. There is also a nonce to prevent replays (i.e, sending the same, valid, data multiple times). If you verify that the nonce is unique and the signature is valid at your server, you can be reasonably sure that it's not fake. Check the part about IAB of [this Google IO presentation](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/dgalpin_android_pirates_and_vampires.pdf) for a discussion.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like the right approach. But how do you check if the signature is valid? I'm using PHP.

Comment: Use PHP's OpenSSl functions. You can get the public key from the development console. Exact code can be found on SO, there is even a project that does this on Google Code, IIRC.

Comment: Will check IIRC, but I doubt the public key will help here. It's stored in client app, so an attacker could extract it and use it to generate a fake transaction.

Comment: You need to read the docs again. The _private_ key is in Google servers. It signs the transactions. Unless someone hacks those, there is no way they could generate a 'fake transaction'. The public key is normally stored in the client app, and is used for _verification_ only. If you have a verification server, it doesn't have to be in the app, it stays on the server. Study the slides I linked for more details.

Comment: I've read the slides. I still don't see how I could verify the transaction without the private key. If it lives only in Google Servers, then my PHP must somehow make a query to those servers.

Comment: Read them again and this as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_encryption Private key-> signs, Public key->verifies. You only need the public key to verify, and it is available.

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know the public key could be used for that. In that case, all I need is to find a PHP code snippet that does this verification. I'll get back to you when I've found it :)

Comment: Not that hard to find: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/. It doesn't seem very active, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @l33t did you find a PHP code snippet? I want my server to verify if an in-app Play or PayPal MPL payment is verified, but can't find any example code

Comment: @Diego, no I didn't. Maybe we should start a bounty for server-side code samples? E.g. PHP and ASP.NET.

Comment: @l33t this function should work according to several posts, but it's always returning 0 (false) somehow, I didn't figure out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261977/php-server-side-iab-verification-openssl-verify-always-returns-0

Comment: @l33t for PayPal, I got this working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252360/580001-invalid-request-0-paypal-php