# API callback URL doesn't work for Android in app purchases through Google checkout

Tags: android, google-checkout

I want Google checkout to call my servlet when ever I receive a order

I entered my servlet url into the API callback URL field and selected Notification as XML (the url was https) and when some in ap purchases were made I received no call

Has anyone got this working? or is this another feature that does not work Android along with email notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is another feature that doesn't work as you think it should.

What appears to happen is that the Play store hijacks the notification event for its own purposes. You never get a notice.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to call your own server with the transaction data. The challenge is to do this in a secure manner.

Here is a thread discussing possible implementations:

[How do I verify Android in-app-billing transactions on MY server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379819/how-do-i-verify-android-in-app-billing-transactions-on-my-server)